# Bash on Windows 10, no loop devices

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10-desktop

I've just tried Bash on my Windows 10 PC, and it works fine. However, I found that there is no such thing as loop devices by `ls /dev/`, and `modprobe loop` gives an error output.

Does it mean this Bash doesn't support loop devices at all or is there a solution for mounting an image as a loop device?

Comment: `bash` is simply a shell, a program that lets you run commands, it's not an operating system with devices and modules to `modprobe`.

Comment: Why is the [`c`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag relevant?

Comment: @iRove Thanks for you correction, it is for the reason that I was dealing with my c demo and come across such a problem, also for I habitually  
associate something about OS to c. （and plus some mistake）￣▽￣~

Answer (score 12):

[Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl/about) 1 (WSL, formerly known as Bash on Ubuntu on Windows) did not support loop devices.  There was a [feature request](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/13432110-mount-image-as-loop-device) and an issue about it on Microsoft's [Git repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1691).

WSL 2, however, [does support loop devices](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4980).

```
$ uname -a
Linux Blade 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Mar 2 00:30:59 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ fallocate -l 1G test.img

$ mkfs.ext3 test.img
mke2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Discarding device blocks: done
Creating filesystem with 262144 4k blocks and 65536 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 549cca4d-a65f-4f4f-8428-e324feaed3d0
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (8192 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

$ sudo mount -o loop test.img /media/

$ ls /media/
lost+found
```

Answer (score -3):

Do you know that Bash is just a shell (something that reads your commands, executes them, pipes between them and permits you to write scripts) and is **not** an operating system?

Loop devices are part of the Linux kernel, and they simply don't exist in the Windows kernel.

Comment: When you use "Add/Remove Windows Features" to acquire Bash on Windows 10 Anniversary Update you get not just a shell, but an entire Ubuntu userspace.  And a Windows kernel layer that emulates Linux syscalls.  (The feature is very inaccurately named)  So while you are correct about the limited scope of the bash shell, that's completely irrelevant to the situation asked about.

Comment: @iharob: Ubuntu is a distribution (or actually a family of them: xubuntu, kubuntu, server, etc), which has an operating system (kernel and user mode utilities) plus applications, plus a package manager.  "Ubuntu userspace" means that this Windows 10 feature has the exact set of non-kernel binaries that ship with Ubuntu Linux, making real Linux syscalls.

Comment: @iharob: Also, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system)) disagrees with you, and [so does the Ubuntu project itself](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop)

Comment: @BenVoigt It's just the exact opposite of Wine. While it just allows to run Linux binaries in a Windows kernel by emulating Linux's system calls. It's still all about **running binaries** and not emulating a full system with it's inputs and outputs. So, I still don't see what's irrelevant in my answer.

Comment: @RyanB: Because "it's not part of bash" is absolutely useless for differentiating between features that are available in this emulated environment, and those that aren't.  Filesystems aren't part of bash, yet the "Ubuntu inside Windows" technology provides two.  `ssh` isn't part of bash, yet "Ubuntu inside Windows" makes it work as if all the Linux tcpip kernel modules were there.  Looking at the shell gives you zero insight into whether a particular Linux kernel module has an emulation or not.

Comment: @RyanB I know bash is a shell also inside the shell there is flesh
and skeleton. It seems that M$ has made a perfect shell but not enough kernel emulation. So as your opinion, is it possible that such a loop file feature will be supported in the future.